# Examining jsonb object values in trigger WHEN clause

Tags: json, postgresql, triggers, jsonb

I have a trigger in **postgresql 12** that fires like so:

```sql
WHEN (OLD.some_jsonb_object_column IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.some_jsonb_object_column)
```

I would like to only run this trigger when values have changed, and not run them if only keys have changed. In this use case, it can be guaranteed that we are not adding and removing keys at the same time. I do not know what the object keys will be ahead of time, so I cannot get the values via `->>`.

I have tried something akin to:

```sql
WHEN (jsonb_each(OLD.some_jsonb_object_column) IS DISTINCT FROM jsonb_each(NEW.some_jsonb_object_column))
```

which results in the error:
`set-returning functions are not allowed in trigger WHEN conditions`

Is there a way to get the values of a jsonb object without using a set-returning function?

Comment: "*and not run them if only keys have changed*" - do you mean to not fire the trigger if (only) keys where added or removed?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what I meant is if the key "name" has changed from 'this_key_name' to 'that_key_name'. I still want to run them if keys (and therefore values) are added or removed.

Comment: How would you distinguish that from removing the key `name` and adding a new key with `this_key_name`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's a good question, and something I'd not thought of.  In this particular use case, however, it can be guaranteed that we are not adding and removing keys at the same time.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thinking about this more... whoops. "do you mean to not fire the trigger if (only) keys where added or removed?" - yes, that is what I mean, with the addendum that the values have remained the same.

Answer (score 1):

To test if a new key has been added:

```
key_added := EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM json_object_keys(NEW.some_jsonb_object_column) AS n
                     EXCEPT
                     SELECT *
                     FROM json_object_keys(OLD.some_jsonb_object_column) AS o
                    );
```

Similarly, you can check if a key was removed.

That should solve your problem.